How can I remove std::function elements from std::list?
I have a std::list which has std::function as its elements. I can add new elements to it but I can't remove such elements from the list.
The code:
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<std::function<void(int)>> handlers;
    auto f1 = [](int i) { /* do something */ };

    handlers.push_back(f1);
    std::cout << "added handler\n";

    handlers.remove(f1);
    std::cout << "removed handler\n";
}

The above code does not compile and gives the following error.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\list(1666): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::function<void (int)>
          ]

Then I checked the list header and found that std::list::remove depends on std::list::remove_if and an equality comparison operator which std::function does not have, thus producing the error.
// in <list> header file

auto remove(const _Ty& _Val) { // erase each element matching _Val
    return remove_if([&](const _Ty& _Other) { return _Other == _Val; });
}

How can I prevent this error? This seems to be an error with the standard library itself. Is there any workaround for this problem?
EDIT: I am using C++20. The comparison operator has been removed in C++20. So is there any alternative to the equality operator in C++20?

Do note the operators we not really removed in C++20. bool operator==( const std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>& f, std::nullptr_t ) noexcept; still exists and C++20's new comparison rules means the other operators are no longer needed as they can be synthesized from the before mentioned operator.

The standard only provides comparison to a nullptr.

I've changed the C++11 tag to C++20 since that is apparently what is being used.

One option would be to wrap your functions in a smart pointer. Then you could do pointer comparisons instead of function comparisons.

@NathanOliver It would be better if you could write an answer about synthesizing other comparison operators from bool operator==( const std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>& f, std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;

@john I thought of that....but what need of little overhead (i.e. ref count and dereferencing) if there exists some way to put the equality operators at the correct place

Even pre-C++20, the equality operator could only be used to compare std::function against a null pointer.  AFAIK it's never been supported to compare two std::function with each other.

@akm: I think the "synthesizing comparison operators" only refers to whether operator!= is separately defined, or synthesized from operator== (which is still there).  But regardless, == and != can still only be used to compare a std::function with null, so it doesn't help with your problem and wouldn't be an answer to your question.

It seems clear that, rather than an "error", this was a deliberate omission.  Presumably the standard authors wanted to leave compilers the freedom to implement std::function in a way that didn't have to preserve equality semantics.  For instance, if you defined two different lambdas with the same behavior, the compiler should be allowed to coalesce them into one and use identical std::function objects, which wouldn't be allowed if the two std::functions were required to compare unequal.
